# I don't get the exact meaning of "have + somebody + gerund" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Doctor: well , Paul... let's get u bandaged up, we'll **have you hobbling** out of here in no time

is "hobbling" a gerund? to modify "you"? I'm not sure
please give me some examples like this structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"hobbling" here means "walking akwardly"

"have you" means "get you"  or "arrange for you to be"

> let's get u bandaged up, we'll have you hobbling out of here in no time

could be rewritten as:

> let's get you bandaged up, that will enable you to walk out of here, if perhaps unsteadily, in a very short time.

or

> let's get you bandaged up,and you will be walking again promptly.

"hobbling" is a gerund form serving as a verb, it is what "you" will be doing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm still learning English but I think a similar example of this use of gerund and may be of some help would be:

If I get that guitar in my hands I will have everybody dancing in no time.